# Removing NA column in matrix in a list deletes column names of the matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, na, names

I have code which looks like:

```
mat1 <- matrix(1, nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
mat1[1,1] <- NA
colnames(mat1) <- c(NA, 'Name1')
mat2 <- mat1
mylist <- list(mat1, mat2)

mylist <-  lapply(mylist, function(x)  x[!is.na(colnames(x))])
```

If I remove the column with the name `NA`, the column name `Name1` is also removed from the matrix. How can I delete the `NA` column but keep the column names of the remaining columns of the matrices in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
lapply(mylist, function(x)  x[, !is.na(colnames(x)), drop = FALSE])

#   [[1]]
#     Name1
#[1,]     1

#[[2]]
#     Name1
#[1,]     1
```

Matrices are different than dataframes. In case of matrix, `mat1[1]` returns you first value of the matrix whereas in case of dataframes `mtcars[1]` returns you first column. To subset columns in matrix you always need a preceding comma (`mat[, i]` and not `mat[i]`) but that is not always true for dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` with `complete.cases` on the column names to return a logical vector and use that in `j` index to select the columns of the matrix

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) x[, complete.cases(colnames(x)), drop = FALSE])
 #[[1]]
 #     Name1
 #[1,]     1

 #[[2]]
 #    Name1
 #[1,]     1
```